# Trying to join two simple tables using Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I'm quite a beginner at Symfony 2 and Doctrine 2. I have two models a `Blog` post and `Comment`. They are related to each other by `blog_id` FK inside `comment` table.

I just want to create a simple method that takes a blog id, Retrieves that blog and related comments. Instead of doing another query in lazy-loading the related comments.

Here's what i tried :

```
<?php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class BlogRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getBlogWithComments($id)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
                    SELECT b, c
                    FROM BloggerBlogBundle:Blog b
                    WHERE b.id = :id
                    JOIN b.id c
                    WHERE b.id = c.blog');
        $query->setParameter("id", $id);
        return $query->getResult();

    }
}
```

I'm really a beginner at Doctrine 2. I usually use Query Builder, But i have no idea how to make a join using it. So Tried it in DQL, Couldn't figure it out either.

It gives me this syntax error whenever i try to call `getBlogWithComments` method:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 80: Error: Expected end of string, got
>   'JOIN'

All what i want to know is that, How to write **JOIN** statements using Query Builder and DQL ? Knowing that documentation is not that helpful unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JOIN` with DQL is done by referencing the relationship between the entities and it only needs to go one way. What I mean is `b.comment c` is all that is needed, there is no need for referencing `c.blog`.

```
public function getBlogWithComments($id)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
           ->createQuery('
                SELECT b, c
                FROM BloggerBlogBundle:Blog b
                JOIN b.comment c
                WHERE b.id = :id
            ')
            ->setParameter("id", $id)
            ->getResult();

}
```

Comment: Ok, That worked. But when i run it again, I get an error in the view `Key "title" for array with keys "0" does not exist in BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:show.html.twig at line 3`.

Comment: That is telling you the `blog` (or what ever you called it) is an array. So you need use twig's `for` statement to loop thru the `blog` array for each `blog` post.

Comment: Oh, That worked too. But i wonder why does it return an array ? I'm only retrieving one blog with its comments. As i've checked, the array only have one element `blog[0]` which contains the whole blog object with the related comments.

Comment: Queries in general have a potential to return multiple objects, because of this it will always return an array. Since you know that it will always be one post you could change the the function in your repository to return the object by doing something like $query = $this->getEntityManager()...; return $query[0];

Comment: Ok, I've changed `getResult()` with `getSingleResult()`.